# Troubles with Django MultiValueField

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am writing an app on Google app engine using a zip of Django 1.0.2 because I am using appengine patch. (Yes, this is an old setup.)

I am trying to implement a MultiValueField and it's not working.  As an example, I took exactly the code from http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/django-forms-edit-inline/multiwidgets-templates/ and put CMSChangeFields into my form as follows

```
# In models
class Foo(db.Model):
  foo = db.StringProperty()
  bar = db.StringProperty()

# In forms
class FooForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  foo = fields.CMSChangeFields()
  class Meta:
    model = models.Foo
```

If I comment out foo in FooForm, I see two edit fields. If I leave foo in, I see "[[ UNDEFINED VARIABLE ]]", which is what I've set TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID to in my settings.py.

What is happening?

I see there may be a mismatch between Foo.foo and FooForm.foo types, but  I'm not sure.

Alternatively, how do I debug this? I've been overriding **init** methods of the fields, forms, etc., and logging things, but I can't tell what's amiss.

If I try to use the debugger, it literally takes >10 minutes to start up, and uses the wrong source files (the google_appengine version of Django instead of my zip file), even though I've been over the project settings carefully.  What I'm saying is the debugger is defying me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever runs across this, my problem was returning None from my widget decompress.  Any value coming from decompress must have the same number of subscriptable values as widgets in the MultiWidget (in my case two).  If foo is None, then foo[1] is bad. Unfortunately, Django 1.0.2 reported that problem with an empty value.